# I can't remember her birthday!

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge, lateral-thinking, number-sequence

My Persian friend said:

> I will meet you in New York on my birthday.

But I can't remember her birthday! I only found this riddle related to her birthday in old chats.

$(y+z)/y = (y)/z = (A+10)/10 $

$x_1 =2,x_2 =3,x_3 =5,x_4 =7,...  => B=x_1x_6x_{16}$

> متولد شده ام B/A من در تاریخ

translation:

> I was born in B/A

Can you tell me when I will meet her in New York?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will meet her on

> September 9

because

> The first equation is about golden ratio: $(y+z)/y=y/z=(1+\sqrt5)/2\approx1.618$, so $A\approx6.18$.
>  The second equation is about primes: $x_i$ represents the $i$th prime, so $B=2\cdot13\cdot53=1378$.
>  Since your friend is Persian, she is probably wrote her birth date in Persian calendar: **1378/6/18**. It corresponds to **1999/9/9** in Gregorian calendar. So, her birthday is on September 9th.

Comment: Why truncate at 6.18 exactly? Why not 6.1, or 6.2 with rounding? (Sorry for putting this comment here, this is not a problem in the answer, but since there are some un-rot13able mild spoilers here, I didn't want to put it too near the question.)

Comment: Because the golden ratio is often known as 1.618, not 1.62.